# Projectile motion with drag

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to calculate the initial velocity $v_0$ and air time of a projectile. I've successfully done it without drag using the following equations:
$v = v_0 - g  t_1$ ($t_1$ = time to the highest point, given; $g$ = gravity, given)
$$(1)\;\; 0 = v_0 - g t_1  =>  v_0 = g t_1;$$

And now to calculating $t_2$ (second part of the trajectory). $y_0$ = starting point of the trajectory, $y_1$ = end point (both are given):
$$(2)\;\; y_1 = y_0 + h - (0 t_2) - \frac 12 g t_2 ^2;$$

($h$ = height)

$$(3)\;\; y_0 + h = y_0 + v_0t_1 - \frac 12 g t_1 ^2;$$
$$h = g t_1 - \frac 12 g t_1 ^2;$$

$$(2)\;\; y_1 = y_0 + g t_1 - \frac 1 2 g t_1 ^2 -\frac 12 g t_2 ^2;$$

For simplicity sake let's assume that $c = y_0 + g t_1 - \frac 1 2 g t_1 ^2 - y_1;$ 
$$
\implies \frac 12 g t_2 ^2 = c; \\\\  \implies t_2 = \sqrt{\frac {2c} g}
$$

So we have:
$$v_0 = g t_1;$$
$$t_2 = \sqrt{\frac {2c} g}$$

How can I add drag into my equations? I've tried using $ma = mg - bv$ with no success whatsoever. Could someone please explain me in detail how can I find $v_0$ and $t_2$ with drag? I'm not that strong in calculus.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is a reason that physics classes ignore drag-it's hard.  I don't believe there is a closed form, so you have to do it numerically.  Air drag is proportional to the square of the velocity, in contrast to the drag equations you often see in physics. So, with $h=$height, $v_0=$ initial velocity, $C_D=$drag coefficient, $v=$ velocity, $m=$mass, $g=$acceleration of gravity, $\rho=$ density of air, $A=$ area of object, you have $$\frac {dv}{dt}=-g\pm\frac 1{2m} \rho v^2 C_D A$$ where the $\pm$ sign depends upon whether the current velocity is up or down.  You can integrate this numerically to get the trajectory and flight time.